# IPython: how do I pipe something into a Python script

Tags: python, pipe, ipython

I understand I can run a script in IPython via `run test.py` and debug from there.

But how do I pipe an output into test.py? For example, normally I could run in the command line like `grep "ABC" input.txt | ./test.py`, but how do I do the same thing in IPython?

Thanks!

Comment: Not familiar with IPython. Any reason you can't use sys.stdin or the fileinput module?

Comment: @Triptych I want to debug with that particular input, generated by grep.

Comment: Try using the [fileinput module](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) and see how it goes. But to really answer this question: yes, you can do it but it depends on how the python is written.

Comment: Do you mean you want to simulate user input to ipython?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside the Python script you should be reading from sys.stdin:

```
import sys

INPUT = sys.stdin

def do_something_with_data(line):
    # Do your magic here
    ...
    return result

def main():
    for line in INPUT:
        print 'Result:', do_something_with_data(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Inside the iterative interpreter you can use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module mock sys.stdin.

```
In[0]: from test.py import *
In[1]: INPUT = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'ABC', 'input.txt'], \
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
In[2]: main()
```

You can also pipe the output to a file and just read from the file. For practical purposes stdin is just another file.

```
In[0]: ! grep "ABC" input.txt > output.txt
In[1]: INPUT = open('output.txt')
In[2]: main()
```