# piping from shell into jupyter notebook cell

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, csvkit

Does anyone know how to stream the output of a shell command (a chain of csvkit tool invocations) into a jupyter notebook cell, but specifically into a Pandas DataFrame.  From the cell's content it would look something like this:

```
 output = !find /path -name "*.csv" | csvstack ... | csvgrep ... 
 df = DataFrame.read_csv(output)
```

only the above isn't really work.  The output of the shell is very large millions of rows, which Pandas can handle just fine, but I don't want the output to be loaded into memory in its entirety as a string.

**I'm looking for a piping/streaming solution that allows Pandas to read the output as it comes.**

Comment: .@Dmitry  Read csv into clipboard, then pd. read_clipboard?  As, far a know pandas does not handle streams..

Answer (score 4):

I figured out a workaround. Though not actually piping, but it saves some disk I/O expense:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
output = !(your Unix command)
df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(output.n))
```

Comment: For those needing to distinguish stdout and stderr, the `%%capture` cell magics offers a nice option.  See [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-capture) and [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.utils.capture.html). Looks akin to oLas's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24776049/8508004) using `%%bash` cell magics but offers another route.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can do it by letting pandas read from STDIN:

Python script:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin)
print(df)
```

Shell command line:

```
!find /path -name "*.csv" | csvstack ... | csvgrep ... | python our_pyscript.py
```

please pay attention at the last part: `| python our_pyscript.py`

You may also want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661835/ipython-how-do-i-pipe-something-into-a-python-script)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "named pipes" would be useful in your case.

In shell:

```
mkfifo MYFIFO
head myfile.txt > MYFIFO
```

In notebook:

```
with open('MYFIFO', 'rt') as f:
    print(f.readline())
```

A few good internet searches should give you the information you need to use named pipes safely and effectively. Good luck!